# Julia, generate array of four, Int8 integers between 1:3, do I need a package?

Tags: random, integer, julia

Julia 1.5.3 on Ubuntu. I'm trying to simply generate an array of four, Int8 integers, comprised of the range from 1:3. Tried a bunch of different syntax but just get errors.  I can't control both the type (Int8), and the number or returns (4). Thx. J

```
rand(1:3, 4) # works
rand(Int8, 4) # works
rand(Int8, 1:3, 4) #error
rand(Int8, 4, 1:3) #error
rand(Int8(1:3), 3) #error
```

Comment: You want `Int8.(1:3)` here.

Comment: rand(Int8.(1:3), 4)   # works!

Comment: You can also just convert your integers after sampling: `Int8.(rand(1:3, 4))`

Comment: Thanks guys, aside I really think you should put these answers in short replies rather than comments, only so you get the credit you deserve.  A one line answer/reply is also very good!  Is this breaking some etiquette?  Your answers might be short but at this stage with new language there is very little on the web, so these may be very useful to others.

Comment: Another comment (sorry): I think it's better to use `rand(Int8(1):Int8(3), 4)`. The reason is that `Int8.(1:3)` first creates a unit range of `Int64`, and then converts it to a `Vector{Int8}`, while `Int8(1):Int8(3)` directly creates a non-allocating `UnitRange{Int8}`.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot that broadcasting allocates, not sure if that's a bug actually. `@btime map(Int8, 1:z[])  setup=(z=Ref(3));` is fast and zero allocations, as is `@btime Int8(1):Int8(z[])  setup=(z=Ref(3));` of course. That said, it's difficult to imagine either of these being a bottleneck.

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant and efficient would be:

```
rand(UnitRange{Int8}(1,3), 4)
```

### EDIT

#### Benoit Pasquier pointed out `Int8(1):Int8(3)` and indeed he is right.

This results in a more efficient assembly code because the type check can be avoided by the compiler (of course only when `1` and `3` are concrete values).

Here is how to find out:

```
julia> @code_native (:)(Int8(1),Int8(3))
        .text
; ┌ @ range.jl:5 within `Colon'
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    %ecx, %eax
; │┌ @ range.jl:287 within `UnitRange'
; ││┌ @ range.jl:292 within `unitrange_last'
; │││┌ @ int.jl:86 within `-'
        leal    -1(%rax), %r8d
; │││└
; │││┌ @ operators.jl:352 within `>='
; ││││┌ @ int.jl:442 within `<='
        cmpb    %dl, %al
; │││└└
        movzbl  %dl, %ecx
        movzbl  %r8b, %edx
        cmovlel %ecx, %edx
; │└└
        popq    %rbp
        retq
        nopl    (%rax,%rax)
; └
```

Compared to:

```
julia> @code_native UnitRange{Int8}(1,3)                                   
        .text                                                              
; ┌ @ range.jl:287 within `UnitRange'                                      
        pushq   %rbp                                                       
        movq    %rsp, %rbp                                                 
        subq    $32, %rsp                                                  
        movq    %rcx, %rax                                                 
; │┌ @ number.jl:7 within `convert'                                        
; ││┌ @ boot.jl:749 within `Int8'                                          
; │││┌ @ boot.jl:639 within `toInt8'                                       
; ││││┌ @ boot.jl:624 within `checked_trunc_sint'                          
        movsbq  %al, %rcx                                                  
        cmpq    %rax, %rcx                                                 
        jne     L49                                                        
; │└└└└                                                                    
; │ @ boot.jl within `UnitRange'                                           
        movq    %rdx, %r8                                                  
; │ @ range.jl:287 within `UnitRange'                                      
; │┌ @ range.jl:292 within `unitrange_last'                                
; ││┌ @ int.jl:86 within `-'                                               
        leaq    -1(%rax), %rdx                                             
; ││└                                                                      
; ││┌ @ operators.jl:352 within `>='                                       
; │││┌ @ int.jl:442 within `<='                                            
        cmpq    %r8, %rax                                                  
; ││└└                                                                     
        cmovleq %r8, %rdx                                                  
; │└                                                                       
; │┌ @ number.jl:7 within `convert'                                        
; ││┌ @ boot.jl:749 within `Int8'                                          
; │││┌ @ boot.jl:639 within `toInt8'                                       
; ││││┌ @ boot.jl:624 within `checked_trunc_sint'                          
        movsbq  %dl, %rcx                                                  
        cmpq    %rdx, %rcx                                                 
        jne     L72                                                        
; │└└└└                                                                    
        addq    $32, %rsp                                                  
        popq    %rbp                                                       
        retq                                                               
; │┌ @ number.jl:7 within `convert'                                        
; ││┌ @ boot.jl:749 within `Int8'                                          
; │││┌ @ boot.jl:639 within `toInt8'                                       
; ││││┌ @ boot.jl:624 within `checked_trunc_sint'                          
L49:                                                                       
        movabsq $throw_inexacterror, %r8                                   
        movl    $243577088, %ecx                # imm = 0xE84B100          
        movq    %rax, %rdx                                                 
        callq   *%r8                                                       
        ud2                                                                
L72:                                                                       
        movabsq $throw_inexacterror, %rax                                  
        movl    $243577088, %ecx                # imm = 0xE84B100          
        callq   *%rax                                                      
        ud2                                                                
        nopl    (%rax,%rax)                                                
; └└└└└
```

Comment: I think you mean `rand(UnitRange{Int8}(1,3), 4)` (note the `8`).

Comment: What about `rand(Int8(1):Int8(3), 4)`?